# Java, setting layout to null

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have been using a null layout and I alot of people will say it shouldn't be done this way. Is there a better way?

Some code as example:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main{
public static void main(String args[]){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Click");

    //JFrame, frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //JPanel, panel
    panel.setLayout(null); //<<---- Is this correct?
    frame.add(panel);

    //JButton, button
    button.setBounds(25, 25, 100, 60); //<<---- Is this correct?
    panel.add(button);

   }
}
```

Comment: There's a reason people say not to use `null` layouts and instead make use of appropriate layout managers. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: The designers of the API, way back in the late 90's fore saw the issues that might occur with cross platform development of GUI's and designed the layout management API at the core of the framework.  If you look into more modern frameworks, like Android and iOS, they either have had or are introducing layout managers into their frameworks for the same reasons there desktop counterparts have them, life is just simpler.  Once you get use to using layout managers, you will not want to do without them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a better way?

Layout managers, layout managers, layout managers.  If the default provided layout managers aren't doing what you want, either use a combination of layout managers or maybe try some of the freely available layout managers, like MigLayout (and use them in combination with other layout managers as required)

With your code...

[image: Without Layout Manager]

Using a `GridBagLayout`

[image: With Layout Manager]

The button is slightly bigger, because it's taking into account the actual requirements of the button (text and font size), but will always add an additional 100 pixels to the width and 60 pixels to the height.

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Click");

        //JFrame, frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //JPanel, panel
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.add(panel);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.ipadx = 100;
        gbc.ipady = 60;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(25, 25, 0, 0);
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

        panel.add(button, gbc);

    }
}
```

Now, if all I do is add `button.setFont(button.getFont().deriveFont(64f));` we end up with...

Your code on the left, my code on the right...

[image: Wow to null layouts]

And if you think that's been overly dramatic, different OS's will do worse things to you then that