# adding Card Layout to JFrame Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, cardlayout

I am new to Java. I want to add my cardlayout to JFrame. I want to do this because I can exit the frame (window) when I click on exit button by closing JFrame. The below program is extending JFrame. But I would like to declare JFrame and add the card on it. I tried but is not happening. Also I would like set card1 Jpanel to 500 (width), 500 (height) but comes on full screen.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TestCard extends JFrame {
    JButton b;
    JTextArea TA;
    JPanel cards;
    JPanel card1;
    JPanel card2;
    CardLayout card;
    final String card1Text = "One";
    final String card2Text = "Two";

    TestCard() {       
        myCard();       
    }

    public void myCard() {

        card = new CardLayout();
        cards = new JPanel(card);

        card1 = new JPanel(null);    
        card1.setBackground(new Color(255,0,0));
        card1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        cards.add(card1, card1Text);

            b = new JButton("Exit");
            b.setBounds(300, 500, 170, 50);
            b.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            card1.add(b);

            TA = new JTextArea();    
            TA.setBounds(300,200,500,250);
            TA.setBackground(Color.white);
            card1.add(TA);


            add(cards);

            card.show(cards, card1Text);

            b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                }
            });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestCard cardLayoutTest = new TestCard();
        cardLayoutTest.setVisible(true);       
        cardLayoutTest.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);    
    }

}
```

Comment: `card1 = new JPanel(null)` would be the start of your problems

Comment: If I do not make it null, then i am unable to set the size of my button and textarea

Comment: @Rajesh use a layoutManager. there are several. best i worked with are Borderlayout, Gridbaglayout and formlayout

Comment: will setbounds work in Borderlayout and other layout managers?

Comment: How to add card(cardlayout) on frame?

Comment: @Rajesh card layout don't work with absolute layout. So either you must use layout managers everywhere or you cannot use card layout.

Comment: @Rajesh `setBounds` are used by layout managers to facilitate their algorithms, they won't read the result, layout managers may use `getPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` to make determinations about how to layout a component, but are within their rights to ignore all of them

Comment: *"I want to add my cardlayout to JFrame. I want to do this **because** I can exit the frame (window) when I click on exit button by closing JFrame."* (scratches head) I don't see how the 2nd sentence explains the first.

Answer (score 2):

> But I would like to declare JFrame and add the card on it

One of the first things you need to understand about a `JFrame` is that's multilayered...

[image: JFrame layers]

When you add components to a `JFrame`, they are (typically) added to the `contentPane`.  See [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html).

So, this is the first problem you need to overcome, when referencing the container in `CardLayout`, you shouldn't rely on the instance of `JFrame`, but instead use `JFrame#getContentPane`

Okay, start by remove `extends JFrame` and start by making an instance of a `JFrame`...

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestCard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestCard();
    }

    public TestCard() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Okay, so, that's not very exciting, we need something to display on it...

```
public class ACardPane extends JPanel {

    private JButton btn;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public ACardPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        btn = new JButton("Exit");
        add(btn, gbc);

        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        textArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea), gbc);
    }

}
```

Okay, now we need to actually add this to the frame....

We need to modify the start code to something like this...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");

CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
frame.setLayout(cardLayout);
frame.add(new ACardPane(), "One");
cardLayout.show(frame.getContentPane(), "One");

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

frame.setVisible(true);
```

This will create a frame, which is maximised, with the text area occupying as much of the space as it can.

If you don't want to be maximised, the change `frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` to `frame.pack()` instead

I'd recommend having a look at

- [Create a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: Hi, it works, but you have given textArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);but it is not getting controlled by this size, it occupies the maximum place.

Comment: Yep, I set up to occupy the available size of its container, with a preferred size of 20 columns and 40 rows, this is why pack works. If you prefer, try removing the lines with weightx/y and fill and how it changes

Comment: Hi, now i am able to control TextArea size. but I had set btn.setBounds(20,20,50,100); to button which is not controlled

Comment: <sigh> Both the button and text area are under the control of the layout manager, try resizing the window and see what happens. The short answer, if you're using setBounds, then you're doing something wrong

Comment: after removing setbounds for button, I resized the window. Textarea is getting resized but button size remains the same.

Comment: And ... what?  That's how I designed it - just so you, I've used of the more complex (and flexible) layout managers to do this

Comment: [And this why you want to use layout managers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249871/java-setting-layout-to-null/33249927#33249927)

Comment: I have done something in AS3 which has scenes to display different pages. Here I found cardLayout was similar. So basically i want to switch between several pages. So I understood that cardlayout should be kept under someother layout. what is the best layout i can use for card layout?

Comment: Yes, CardLayout will allow you to (simply) switch between multiple views; CardLayout is a layout manager in its own right, each view would then have its own layout manager, which you would use will depend on what you want to achieve for each view